# How to subtract two date in Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

I have a query with 2 dates

```
my_metric {key="01234",endpoint="http-metrics",instance="",job="my-metrics",time1="2020-08-09 14:04:21 +0000 UTC",time2="2020-08-10 12:12:26 +0000 UTC"}
```

I want to add to the grafana new calculation field that we do substract of two fields that exist in my DB. ( time 1 , time 2) .It is not possible to create new field in the DB so I want to know if it possible to create new field like SUM , COUNT but the field should do subtract how two dates for example 24.08.2010 10:00 24.8.2010 12:00 I want to get 2 hour different

is it possible ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Please share the steps you've already tried (if only searching for answers on the web) so that people can better advise you as to how you might proceed.

Comment: I want to add to the grafana new calculation field that we do substract of two fields that exist in my DB. ( time 1 , time 2) .It is not possible to create new field in the DB so I want to know if it possible to create new field like SUM , COUNT but the field should do subtract how two dates for example 24.08.2010 10:00 24.8.2010 12:00 I want to get 2 hour different

Comment: You should probably add that additional explanation to your question.  People may not spot it in a comment.